# Sort array of objects by keys not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have this array of objects:

```js
let ans = [{'a' : 5},{'d' : 3 },{'c' : 0 },{'b' : 4 }];

//Attempt to sort this
ans.sort((a,b)=>{
  return Object.keys(a)[0] > Object.keys(b)[0];
});
console.log(ans);
```

Shouldn't this sort function sort it? If not this how to sort this.

Comment: It is happening because after comparing keys, it is evaluating to boolean, `true` gets converted to `1` but `false` gets converted to `0` instead of `-1`, hence your sort function is not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function provided for `array.sort()` should return a number instead of a boolean. If `a > b`, then a number greater than 0 should be returned. If `a < b`, then a number less than 0.

```js
let ans = [{'a' : 5},{'d' : 3 },{'c' : 0 },{'b' : 4 }];

//Attempt to sort this
console.log(ans.sort((a,b)=>{
  return Object.keys(a)[0] > Object.keys(b)[0] ? 1 : -1;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
ans.sort((a,b)=>{
    return Object.keys(a)[0].localeCompare(Object.keys(b)[0]);
});
```